# Function of a letter in C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I have the following expression:

A = cos(5x),

where x is a letter indicating a generic parameter. 
In my program I have to work on A, and after some calculations I must have a result that must still be a function of x , explicitly.

In order to do that, what kind of variable should A (and I guess all the other variables that I use for my calculations) be?

Many thanks to whom will answer

Comment: I think you need to define "work on" and "function" more clearly. Do you mean that you want to somehow end up with e.g. `5 - sin(x)` (i.e. not a number) as a result? ("I have" is also vague - is it a string or is it C++ code?.)

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, exactly

Comment: the above expression is part of a C++ code

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need precision. In which case, `double` is probably what you want.

You can also use `float` if you need to operate on a lot of floating-point numbers (think in the order of thousands or more) and analysis of the algorithm has shown that the reduced range and accuracy don't pose a problem.

If you need more range or accuracy than double, `long double` can also be used.

Comment: If I use a double I get only a number at the end of my calculations. I want to have a function of x.

Comment: Oh, the way you worded it makes it sound like you were asking for the variable you should be using. In that case, I'm not doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do a *symbolic* calculation, ie

```
A = magic(cos(5 x))
B = acos(A)
print B

> 5 x
```

If so, there isn't a simple datatype that will do this for you, unless you're programming in Mathematica.

The most general answer is "A will be an Expression in some AST representation for which you have a general algebraic solver."

---

However, if you really want to end up with a C++ function you can call (instead of a symbolic representation you can print as well as evaluating), you can just use function composition.  In that case, A would be a

```
std::function<double (double )>
```

or something similar.

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to do a symbolic calculation. How can I do that, even using different datatypes or Mathematica? If i have my C++ already written, is there a simple way to import it in Mathematica?

Comment: What about trying to use Symbolic C++? Actually I tried to download it but I don't manage to compile my program, which contains      #include "symbolicc++" in the preamble (as it should, if I want to use Symbolic)

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used either - you'll have to try them (or look for tutorials) and ask any specific questions you have. In general, symbolic/algebraic manipulation is a complicated subject, but you may be able to manipulate an expression tree and then evaluate it, so long as you don't need to simplify expressions (eg, for speed or precision)

Answer (score 0):

To define function `A(x) = cos(5 * x)`

You may do:

- Regular function:

  ```
  double A(double x) { return std::cos(5 * x); }
  ```
- Lambda:

  ```
  auto A = [](double x) { return std::cos(5 * x); };
  ```

And then just call it as any callable object.

```
A(4.); // cos(20.)
```